# Load record at scrolllistview

Tags: android

I need to prevent against lazy load in my **custom** list-view. so i found that scrollview onscroll listner are helpfull over there i have tryed it but not getting success to implement this functionality.

**Code:**

```
lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(SaxParser2.this, Arr_ActivityName, Arr_AudioScript,Arr_RequestID,Arr_FolderPath,Arr_RequestTo);
    lview.setOnScrollListener(SaxParser2.this);       

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
```

**here is my BaseAdapter**

```
package com.RecordingApp;

import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.Sharedpreferance.GMailSender;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public static Activity context;

    String title[];
    String description[];
    String RequestId[];
    String Folderpath[];
    String RequestTo[];

    boolean b_Flag_Record_or_not = false;
    boolean b_upload_or_not = false;
    boolean start_or_not = false;
    boolean start_play = false;
    boolean upload_or_not = false;
    boolean b_play_or_not = false;
    boolean isplaying2 = false;

    Thread welcomeThread,welcomeThread2;
    int glob_position;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
    int flag_stop_position;
    AudioRecorder recorder;
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation, frameAnimation_play;
    private static String mFileName = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
    Recording login = new Recording();


    MediaPlayer MP_completeRequest = new MediaPlayer();

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] title,
            String[] description, String[] req_id, String[] FolderPath,
            String[] Arr_RequestTo) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.RequestId = req_id;
        this.Folderpath = FolderPath;
        this.RequestTo = Arr_RequestTo;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return title.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtViewTitle;
        TextView txtViewDescription;
        Button record, stop, play, upload;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        glob_position = position;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.record = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.record);

            holder.stop = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stop);
            holder.play = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.play1);
            holder.upload = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.audio_upload);

            holder.record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (isplaying2 == true) {

                    } else {
                        if (b_Flag_Record_or_not == true) {
                        } else {
                            try {

                                holder.record.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_green);
                                b_Flag_Record_or_not = true;
                                b_play_or_not = true;

                                flag_stop_position = position;
                                AuthHandler dataHandler = new AuthHandler();
                                AuthDataset dataset = dataHandler
                                        .getParsednewJobdtl_DataSet();


                                // Login l = new Login();
                                String str_useid = RequestTo[position];
                                recorder = new AudioRecorder(
                                        "/audiometer/shanesh"
                                                + RequestId[position] + "-"
                                                + str_useid);
                                start_or_not = true;
                                recorder.start();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Recording Started",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                CountDownTimer countDowntimer = new CountDownTimer(
                                        120000000, 1000) {
                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    }

                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        try {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    context,
                                                    "Stop recording Automatically ",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            recorder.stop();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                                countDowntimer.start();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                gotoGmail(e);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                gotoGmail(e);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try {

            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/tahoma.ttf");
            holder.txtViewTitle.setTypeface(face);

            holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
            holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);

        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (isplaying2 == true) {
                        mPlayer2.stop();

                        isplaying2 = false;
                    } else {
                    holder.record.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page7_15);
                        if (flag_stop_position == position) {
                            b_Flag_Record_or_not = false;
                            if (start_or_not == true) {
                                b_play_or_not = false;

                                recorder.stop();
                                upload_or_not = true;
                                start_play = true;
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Stoped Recording",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context,
                                        " Please Start recording ",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        } else {

                        }

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    gotoGmail(e);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String temp = SaxParser2.str_completeORpendingFlag;

                if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                    try {

                        final MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        try {

                            mPlayer.setDataSource(Folderpath[position]);

                            mPlayer.prepare();

                            final int welcomeScreenDisplay = mPlayer
                                    .getDuration();
                            welcomeThread = new Thread() {
                                int wait = 0;

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        isplaying2 = true;
                                        mPlayer.start();
                                        while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                                            sleep(100);
                                            wait += 100;
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                    } finally {
                                        isplaying2 = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            welcomeThread.start();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            gotoGmail(e);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        gotoGmail(e);
                    }
                } else if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                    try {

                        if (b_play_or_not == true) {

                        } else {

                            String str_useid = RequestTo[position];
                            java.io.File file = new java.io.File(Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "/audiometer/", "shanesh"
                                    + RequestId[position] + "-" + str_useid
                                    + ".amr");
                            if (file.exists()) {

                                Toast.makeText(context, "Playing",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                mPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
                                try {
                                    mPlayer2.setDataSource(Environment
                                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                            + "/audiometer/shanesh"
                                            + RequestId[position]
                                            + "-"
                                            + str_useid + ".amr");
                                    mPlayer2.prepare();
                                    mPlayer2.start();
                                    isplaying2 = true;

                                    final int welcomeScreenDisplay = mPlayer2
                                            .getDuration();
                                    /**
                                     * create a thread to show splash up to
                                     * splash time
                                     */
                                    welcomeThread = new Thread() {
                                        int wait = 0;

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            try {mPlayer2.prepare();

                                                while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                                                    sleep(100);
                                                    wait += 100;
                                                }
                                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                            } finally {
                                                welcomeThread2 = new Thread() {
                                                    int wait = 0;

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run() {
                                                        try {
                                                            mPlayer2.start();
                                                            while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                                                                sleep(100);
                                                                wait += 100;
                                                            }
                                                        } catch (Exception e) {

                                                        } finally {
                                                            // frameAnimation_play.stop();
                                                            isplaying2 = false;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                };
                                                welcomeThread2.start();

                                            }
                                        }
                                    };
                                    welcomeThread.start();


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    gotoGmail(e);
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, " File Not Found ",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        gotoGmail(e);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        holder.upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                glob_position = position;
                // String str_useid = RequestTo[position];
                if (upload_or_not == true) {
                    try {
                        new xyz().execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        gotoGmail(e);
                    }
                }

            }

        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class xyz extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            try {
                this.dialog.setMessage("Uploading...Please Wait..");
                dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                this.dialog.show();

                // put your code which preload with processDialog
            } catch (Exception e) {
                gotoGmail(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

            }
            it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient con = new it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient();
            try {
                String str_useid = RequestTo[glob_position];
                con.connect("URL");
                con.login("as", "asdasd");
                con.changeDirectory("/rangam/RequestContent/audio");
                con.setPassive(true);
                con.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);

                con.upload(new java.io.File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/audiometer/shanesh"
                        + RequestId[glob_position] + "-" + str_useid + ".amr"));

                String filename = "/shanesh" + RequestId[glob_position] + "-"
                        + str_useid + ".amr";
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect(true);
                String MachineName = Machinelist.str_Machinename;
                sendFlagToServer(RequestId[glob_position], filename,
                        MachineName);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                gotoGmail(e);
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                try {
                    this.dialog.dismiss();
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);
                    alertbox.setTitle("Message");
                    alertbox.setMessage(":: Uploaded Successfully  ::");
                    alertbox.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                        int arg1) {
                                    Intent intent_request = new Intent(context,
                                            SaxParser2.class);
                                    intent_request.putExtra("value", Machinelist.str_UIDValue);
                                    intent_request.putExtra("machineName",
                                            Machinelist.str_Machinename);
                                    intent_request.putExtra("captureBack_or_not", 2);
                                    context.startActivity(intent_request);
                                    context.finish();
                                }
                            });
                    alertbox.show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    gotoGmail(e);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void sendFlagToServer(String requestID, String filename,
            String machineName) {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        OutputStreamWriter request = null;
        String MachineName = Machinelist.str_Machinename;
        URL url = null;
        String parameters = "RequestID=" + requestID + "&FileName=" + filename
                + "&MachineName=" + MachineName + "&RequestType=A";
        try {
            url = new URL(
                    "URL");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            request.write(parameters);
            request.flush();
            request.close();
            String line = "";
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            isr.close();
            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            gotoGmail(e);
        }

    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

            try {

                context.finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                gotoGmail(e);
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
     void gotoGmail(Exception e) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
        e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        String s = writer.toString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

So first you'll have to define "what is the number of views I'd need to load in order my user not to see that it's lazy loading ?" :

Let's say, you'd want to load 20 rows...

Now in you onscroll, or wherever you want but somewhere like on scroll or Adapter.getView, you'll have to know what is displayed on screen at the moment... Let me explain :

I want to load 20 rows so my user doesn't notice,
I am display 10 of them
and 10 of them are just hidden (not displayed if the guy doesn't scroll).

Now, I wan't to load 10 more when the guy just hit my 15th row
What could be the best way to do that ???

Humm, let's see, trying to find something that returns the (ABSOLUTE) number of the last row displayed on screen - this could be a nice solution.
An otehr solution could be that your 10 or 15th row is the first one displayed on screen ?

etc, etc...

I think stuffs like that should do the trick. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample I grabbed from Net. It is loading the items by `listening to the Scroll` of the `ListView` . For sample it is loading dates in ListView. After reached the end position it will load next 15 dates. It is `Never Ending List` . You can modify the adapter to your custom adapter. The concept is:

1. You have set of data
2. Loading first n no of items
3. Set the scroll listener to the listview
4. If scroll reaches Last Visible Item in Listview , You trigger the worker thread to load additional m no of items.
5. Notify listview from an UI thread.

   ```
   int itemsPerPage = 15;
   boolean loadingMore = false;
   ArrayList<String> myListItems;
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

   //For test data :-)
   Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();

   this.getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

       //useless here, skip!
       @Override
       public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

       @Override
       public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
               int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


           //what is the bottom item that is visible
           int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;             

           //is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load more !
           if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){                 
               Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
               thread.start();
           }
       }
   });


   //Load the first 15 items
   Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
   thread.start();

   }


   //Runnable to load the items 
   private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {           
   @Override
   public void run() {
       //Set flag so we cant load new items 2 at the same time
       loadingMore = true;

       //Reset the array that holds the new items
       myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();


       //Get 15 new listitems
       for (int i = 0; i < itemsPerPage; i++) {        

           //Fill the item with some bogus information
           myListItems.add("Date: " + (d.get(Calendar.MONTH)+ 1) + "/" + d.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + d.get(Calendar.YEAR) );              

           // +1 day :-D
           d.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

       }

       //Done! now continue on the UI thread
       runOnUiThread(returnRes);

   }
   };  


   //Since we cant update our UI from a thread this Runnable takes care of that! 
   private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

       //Loop thru the new items and add them to the adapter
       if(myListItems != null && myListItems.size() > 0){
           for(int i=0;i<myListItems.size();i++)
               adapter.add(myListItems.get(i));
       }

       //Update the Application title
       setTitle("Neverending List with " + String.valueOf(adapter.getCount()) + "     items");

       //Tell to the adapter that changes have been made, this will cause the list to refresh
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       //Done loading more.
       loadingMore = false;
   }
   };
   ```

**EDIT:**
You can get tutorial and full project [here](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-never-ending-list/)

Comment: i know this thing but what about in my case?

Comment: can you provide me Custom list-view.onscrollview